# Location detection in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.4, multilingual

I have implemented multilingualism in my joomla 3.4.5 website. I have two languages, french and English. I would like to make it possible that when a user logs onto this website the site automatically detects the location and based on that location redirects the user to specific language site associated with that location. is it possible to achieve this in Joomla? Please guide me here

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it location based? By default I think the detection is by the accept-language http request header, ie by the browser setting selected by the user. That is usually more reliable and likely to be correct than guessing language based on location guessed by IP address. Or did I misunderstand what you want?

Comment: By default my site first loads the English site. This means that if a user is french he will have to  choose his preferred language at the first visit My ideal scenario is that the site can detect the location . Lets say if it's a francophone country then it automatically loads the french site and vice versa

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about Joomla doing it correct by default. This is because whenever I was doing multi-linguals I followed a checklist that had the part about language filter in it. (In 2.5 you **needed** the list.) Anyway the answer by Lodder explains what I meant. I'd **really** recommend not going by location unless it is required by law or corporate policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't personally base the language on where the user is located. For example, I'm English but lived in Spain for some years, however I would still want to view a site in English, given the choice.

You might want to consider using Joomla's Language Filter plugin.

If you have a look at it, you see an options called **Language Selection for new Visitors.**, which you can set to **Browser Settings**. This will try to detect the browser settings and change the language of the site if possible.

Either that, or use the Language module to allow the user to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it based on geoip.

See:
http://www.metamodpro.com/blog/automatically-switch-language-in-joomla-25.html

However, I personally wouldn't suggest it as you can't assume that everyone in a set country reads that countries language.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is this relevant, but there's an extension which basically redirects a user based on his Geographical Country Code. So in other words it takes the users IP address, looks up the country code and then redirects the user to a different menu item.

The extension is called User GeoIP Location Menu Item redirect. See: https://jdev.l-it.co.za/products/user-geoip-location-menu-item-redirect